# Splitting API Definitions with RTK Query

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have *three* API definitions in my current scenario.

- Groups
- Group Members
- Group Invitations

These routes relate to each other, in that accepting a group invitation will invalidate the list of groups a user has. As a result, I have defined them under the same API as they need to invalidate shared tags.

However, this results in quite a bloated file, as each of those definitions have their own endpoints associated with them. Reading the documentation for [Code Splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) with RTK Query suggests using injectEndpoints. This looks like it will suit my purposes, but I've the documentation has no examples that I can find of how it should be implemented with multiple 'sub' endpoints.

I have a couple questions;

1. If I was to utilize injectEndpoints to extend the *Groups* API with GroupInvitations & GroupMembers seperately, which API should be included in the call to configureScore?
2. Is there a way to inject both endpoints into Groups at once, resulting in a single combinedApi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You always only configure your one `emptyApi` in your store setup. All the other "apis" you get by calling `injectEndpoints` are just a reference to that same api - but with additional types for autocomplete.
2. Sure, just add multiple endpoints to the `endpoints` value of the `injectEndpoints` call.

Comment: I see, thank you :) 

Would it make sense to add this to the documentation on code splitting?

Comment: If you think you can make that any clearer, a Documentation Pull Request is always very welcome :)